# Do I need to pay to change github pages domain?

Tags: github, github-pages

I know that to make repository private, I need to change my plan to paid, but what if I want to change the default username.github.com to a custom domain?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, it doesn't look like you would have to upgrade your GitHub account to use a domain name. From the docs at https://help.github.com/articles/quick-start-setting-up-a-custom-domain/ (the description doesn't mention anything about being a paid customer):

> Pick a custom domain and register it with a DNS provider (if you
>   haven't already done so). A DNS provider is a company that allows
>   users to buy and register a unique domain name and connect that name
>   to an IP (Internet Protocol) address by pointing your domain name to
>   an IP address or a different domain name. A DNS provider may also be
>   called a domain registrar or DNS host.
>
> Set up your custom domain with your DNS provider. Our guides outline
>   how to set up your pages custom domain with your DNS provider
>   depending on the type of custom domain you have.

However, these are the only domain types that are supported by GitHub (https://help.github.com/articles/about-supported-custom-domains/):

```
www subdomain   (www.example.com)
one apex domain & one www subdomain (example.com & www.example.com)
apex domain (example.com)
custom subdomain    (blog.example.com)
```

If you want your GitHub pages site to redirect to your domain (or someone else's) it doesn't look like there's anything stopping you from putting just a simple javascript redirect in your GitHub page to redirect to that page.